# SEIZE BLOCK and Priority

Tags: anylogic

I have a problem with the SEIZE block. Right now agents are accessing resources by following a priority I set. Is it possible, however, that if more than one agent arrives with the same priority, and asks for the same resources, Anylogic stops not knowing to whom to grant the resources?

Answer (score 0):

If two or more agent with the same priority are asking for the same resource then the first one asking will get it. [Here](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/seize.html#task-priority) is more information on the topic.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the resource won't be released to anyone?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A resource that is available and is asked for will be seized. The priority and timing only define which requesting agent will get the resource. If resource isn't being seized then there must be another error.